# error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’ and error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’

Tags: c++

There is my code but I am currently getting these error codes I know there is quite a bit of errors.

So I am confused as to why some of the errors are saying that it is not in scope when it was declared at the top in the public class Employee. Also when I create a subclass from the power class Why is there errors still saying that its not in scope even though they are a subclass from the power class.

I am using the const char * but still getting an error.
Thank you for looking at my code! I really appreciate the input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Employee {

    public:
        Employee ();
        void setEmployeeName (string name);
        void setEmployeeNumber (string EmployeeID);
        void setHireDate (string date);
        string getEmployeeName ();
        string getEmployeeNumber ();
        string getHireDate ();

    protected:
        string employeeName;
        string employeeNumber;
        string hireDate;
};
Employee::Employee () {
    employeeName = "Please Enter a name.";
    employeeNumber = "Please enter an Employee Number";
    hireDate = "Not Avaliable";
}

void Employee::setEmployeeName (string name) {
    employeeName = name;
}

void Employee::setEmployeeNumber (string EmployeeID) {
    employeeNumber = EmployeeID;
}

void Employee::setHireDate (string date) {
    hireDate = date;
}

string Employee::getEmployeeName () {
    return employeeName;
}

string Employee::getEmployeeNumber () {
    return employeeNumber;
}

string Employee::getHireDate () {
    return hireDate;
}

class ProductionWorker : public Employee {

    public:
        ProductionWorker ();
        void setShift (const char * workday);
        void setHourlyPayRate (double payRate);
        const char * getShift ();
        double getHourlyPayRate ();
        void Print ();

    private:
        int workday;
        double hourlyPayRate;
};
ProductionWorker::ProductionWorker () {
    int shift = 0;
    hourlyPayRate = 0.0;
}

void ProductionWorker::setShift (const char * workday) {
    const char * shift = workday;
}

void ProductionWorker::setHourlyPayRate (double payRate) { 
    hourlyPayRate = payRate; 
}

int getShift () { 
    if (const char * shift == 0)
        return "No Shift.";
    else if (const char * shift == 1) 
        return "Day Shift.";
    else if (const char * shift == 2)
        return "Night Shift.";
    else 
        return "Error.";

}

double ProductionWorker::getHourlyPayRate () {
    return hourlyPayRate;
}

void Print () {
    cout << "Name of Employee: " << getemployeeName << endl
         << "Employee ID Number: " << getemployeeNumber << endl
         << "Date of Employment: " << gethireDate << endl
         << "Shift: " << getshift << endl
         << "Pay Rate: " << getHourlyPayRate << endl;
}

int main () {

    ProductionWorker SystemAdmin ();

    SystemAdmin.setEmployeeName ("Michael Alexander");
    SystemAdmin.setEmployeeNumber ("00685193");
    SystemAdmin.setHireDate ("06/20/2019");
    SystemAdmin.setShift (1);
    SystemAdmin.setHourlyPayRate (30.00);

    SystemAdmin.Print ();

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the error CODES

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int getShift()’:
main.cpp:79:6: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
  if (const char * shift == 0)
      ^
main.cpp:79:6: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
main.cpp:80:10: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
   return "No Shift.";
          ^
main.cpp:81:11: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
  else if (const char * shift == 1) 
           ^
main.cpp:81:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
main.cpp:82:10: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
   return "Day Shift.";
          ^
main.cpp:83:11: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
  else if (const char * shift == 2)
           ^
main.cpp:83:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
main.cpp:84:10: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
   return "Night Shift.";
          ^
main.cpp:86:10: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
   return "Error.";
          ^
main.cpp: In function ‘void Print()’:
main.cpp:95:34: error: ‘getemployeeName’ was not declared in this scope
  cout << "Name of Employee: " << getemployeeName << endl
                                  ^
main.cpp:96:33: error: ‘getemployeeNumber’ was not declared in this scope
    << "Employee ID Number: " << getemployeeNumber << endl
                                 ^
main.cpp:97:33: error: ‘gethireDate’ was not declared in this scope
    << "Date of Employment: " << gethireDate << endl
                                 ^
main.cpp:98:20: error: ‘getshift’ was not declared in this scope
    << "Shift: " << getshift << endl
                    ^
main.cpp:99:23: error: ‘getHourlyPayRate’ was not declared in this scope
    << "Pay Rate: " << getHourlyPayRate << endl;
                       ^
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:106:14: error: request for member ‘setEmployeeName’ in ‘SystemAdmin’, which is of non-class type ‘ProductionWorker()’
  SystemAdmin.setEmployeeName ("Longdy Chea");
              ^
main.cpp:107:14: error: request for member ‘setEmployeeNumber’ in ‘SystemAdmin’, which is of non-class type ‘ProductionWorker()’
  SystemAdmin.setEmployeeNumber ("00685193");
              ^
main.cpp:108:14: error: request for member ‘setHireDate’ in ‘SystemAdmin’, which is of non-class type ‘ProductionWorker()’
  SystemAdmin.setHireDate ("06/20/2019");
              ^
main.cpp:109:14: error: request for member ‘setShift’ in ‘SystemAdmin’, which is of non-class type ‘ProductionWorker()’
  SystemAdmin.setShift (1);
              ^
main.cpp:110:14: error: request for member ‘setHourlyPayRate’ in ‘SystemAdmin’, which is of non-class type ‘ProductionWorker()’
  SystemAdmin.setHourlyPayRate (30.00);
              ^
main.cpp:112:14: error: request for member ‘Print’ in ‘SystemAdmin’, which is of non-class type ‘ProductionWorker()’
  SystemAdmin.Print ();
              ^
```

Comment: How many examples of `if`-conditionals have you seen where the condition contains a type, and how many comparisons have you seen between strings and integers?

Comment: This code consists of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors that are easily fixed.

```
void ProductionWorker::Print () {
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and

```
int ProductionWorker::getShift () {
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`Print` and `getShift` are methods of the `ProductionWorker` class so have to be defined as such. You got this right with every other method, but not these two.

Also not

```
ProductionWorker SystemAdmin ();
```

but

```
ProductionWorker SystemAdmin;
```

What you wrote declares a function called `SystemAdmin` where is clear that you really want a variable called  `SystemAdmin`. It's a common beginner mistake,

Unfortunately there are other errors that are hard to understand. You clearly have a lot of confusion about shifts and work days. Unfortunately your code makes little sense here and I'm not sure what to advise unless you can explain what you are trying to do. I suspect that you started out with code that was nearly correct but it just got worse and worse as you tried to fix it, to the point that it no longer makes much sense.